# Handling Db column Null values in Java

Tags: java

I am having this piece of code i have put this check to avoid Null Exception but still getting Null Exception.

```
String sDate;
if(oers.getString("FULFILLMENT_Date")==null)
{
    sDate = "";
}
else
{
    sDate=oers.getString("FULFILLMENT_Date");       
}
```

Comment: What is `oers`? Is it `null`?

Comment: oers is resultset which is not null contains other values

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional null check for `oers` to avoid NullPointerException in case `oers` is null

```
if(oers != null) {
   if(oers.getString("FULFILLMENT_Date")==null)
   {
       sDate = "";
   }
   else
   {
       sDate=oers.getString("FULFILLMENT_Date");       
   }
}
```

Comment: No oers is not null.Even after adding this check, still getting exception

Comment: @Ahsan I verified it many times coz I know i should work well i have found a way round just putting a try catch and setting sDate=""; in catch that makes it work for now

Comment: @Eman Thats ok but you have not found the reason of NPE, which is important.